# Commerce South African Payment method

Tags: 7, commerce

I’m busy with a Drupal 7 Commerce site, and I need a correct and working payment method to handle the payments in ZAR (South African Rand) and not in any other currency.

Comment: Have you got any south African payment service providers in mind?

Comment: Also looking at this, so want to use Drupal Commerce for next project, wondering how much effort it would be to do a PayFast module.

Answer (score 3):

This answer probably is too late, but for the sake of other South African users coming across this question: I have a sandbox module for using [Paygate](https://www.paygate.co.za/) as your payment gateway. It is developed for Drupal 7 Commerce and it's currently live on a few websites I've worked on.

You can get the module [here](http://drupal.org/sandbox/malberts/1772114), but you'll need to know how to use git to download it.

Comment: Never too late! I have contacted you on Drupal, now just got to get round to testing this.